# Recreate Activity when pressing the notification - how to?

Tags: java, android

I have a clickable notification, that opens my application when clicked. Howewer, old activity isn't deleted, so, when I close app, there's the same activity under previous...hope you understand.

So, how can I delete old activity?
The code below is situated in service. And I need to destroy Main activity.

```
void sendNotif() {
        Intent in = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pin = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, in, 0);
        Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(this)
         .setContentTitle("App launched")
         .setContentText("Press to open app")
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
         .setContentIntent(pin)
         .build();            
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        nm.notify(1, notif);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin:

```
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add a flag to your Intent when you create your PendingIntent like this:

```
Intent in = new Intent(this,  getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
PendingIntent pin = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, in, 0);
```

Comment: Can't find FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT.

Comment: Intent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT, reference is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Comment: Yes, I know, but Eclipse gives an error and doesn't find this flag

Comment: Looks like the API I linked is API 15.  Not sure when those particular flags were introduced, but likely you aren't using a compatible version (why eclipse can't find it).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these flags to your intent.

```
in.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) for explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```
onPause()
{
    MainActivity.this.finish();
}
```

Comment: Just be aware if you do this that your activity will also be destroyed  whenever you launch new activity from it (or switch to the Home / do many of the other actions that invoke onPause).

Comment: This isn't right way doing. There are so many case when the onPause will be called and it will result in killing up the activity